# C# - System.NullReferenceException on setting text of a label

Tags: c#

I created a label named `dbgOut`

[image]

I simply try to set the text of the label but I get `System.NullReferenceException`.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Helper;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace test
{

    public partial class test: Form
    {  

        public test()
        {
            dbgOut.Text = "test";

            ...
```

Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is trying to mess with a UI component before initializing it. A call to `InitializeComponent` should be made in the first line of the constructor of the forms so that your UI controls get intiailized and then you can play with them.

More infos: https://www.dotnetperls.com/initializecomponent

Comment: Thank you very much, I am new to C# and was not aware of this. I will accept your answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: Welcome to the C# community then! Hope you like the language.

Comment: If you create a project from the Winforms C# template, this call will be inserted for you.